# spark.read vs spark.sql - Why that is different cost?

Tags: apache-spark

[image]

spark.read vs spark.sql - Why that is different cost?

Both have partition filtering. But, `spark.read(1543.5KiB; s3://a/b/c/target)` speed is too slow. And then more expensive than `spark.sql(2.8KiB; s3://a/b/c/target/dt=20221225)`.

I think, this problem is `spark.read` to get partition columns.

- Listing leaf files and directories for `{N}` paths ...
- Reading all files.

It is true?

Comment: Who sets the costs?

Comment: pyspark dataframe.explain("cost") api?; by zeppelin ui in picture

Comment: Could you compare the sql example with `spark.read.parquet("s3a://path/partition_col=20221225")`? does it show the same diff?

Comment: Too much red ink, especially around `spark.read.parquet()`... E.g. whats the path being read?

Comment: @mezaneicha above of partition path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark is processing data lazy, but is getting schemas non-lazy.
The `spark.sql` is reading metadata (e.g. from Hive) and does not know yet how large the input data set will be. I guess that's whats shown there with the small amount.
The `spark.read.parquet` has to access the actual parquet file and infer the schema (in your red section), therefore the optimizer already knows how large the file will be, thus leading to the larger number and slower processing.

Can you please cache the dataframe and execute an spark action (like `df.show` or `df.count`) and the post the `df.explain` results again. Statistics should be similar after that.

Comment: thx for answer. but same result df.show -> df.explain.

Comment: Did you use df.cache before?